# How to uninstall all USB hubs if keyboard and mouse are running via USB?

Tags: windows, windows-8, usb

I managed to uninstall at least one and then both keyboard and mouse dies. I then have to manually restart. I need to uninstall all USB hubs and roots to see if reinstalling it will fix the USB error I get on Windows 8 x64.

```
unknown device (Code 43)
Hardware Ids: USB\DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR_FAILURE
```

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725873(v=WS.10).aspx

Comment: The thing is that all USB devices do work, and it's only Mouse and Keyboard. I get that error while both disconnected. And none of those steps helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you connect to the machine via RDP from another computer (or even your smartphone), you will be able to control it without the need for a mouse or keyboard to be connected directly to the machine.

Comment: Sadly I do not have a chance to do neither of that. But it makes sense.